# TextInput block change in onChange (preventDefault)?

Tags: react-native

I have to have an uncontrolled text input (for some reason not detailed here). I am trying to block a change from happening in my `<TextInput>`.

Here is my component and here is Snack demo of it - https://snack.expo.io/@noitsnack/textinput-block-onchange

```
class UncontrolledInput extends Component {
    inputRef = null

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput ref={this.refInput} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </View>
        )
    }

    refInput = el => this.inputRef = el

    handleChange = e => {
        const { nativeEvent:{ text } } = e;

        // block i characters
        if (text.includes('i')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? While `preventDefault` and `stopPoropagation` exist in `e` they don't seem to do anything.

Comment: Could you try `e.nativeEvent.preventDefault()`. I won't add as an answer as I am not 100% sure it'll work.

Comment: Hi @Dan ! It caused a crash in Snack - https://snack.expo.io/@noitsnack/textinput-block-onchange :(

Comment: Maybe because it is already too late ? on iOS you could try to do that on the `keyPress` event, on Android `keyPress` event has been added recently in a recent version (0.53 I think).

Comment: Thanks @Théodvn I will upgrade and try in a dummy proejct (im on Android 0.51), when I upgrade should i use `e.nativeEvent.preventDefault()` or `e.preventDefault()`? Should I bother trying `stopPropagation` `returnValue` return false`?

Comment: @Théodvn you were right that `onKeyPress` exists in Android in updated Android (im testing in 0.54), however doing a `e.preventDefault()` etc is not blocking it :(

Comment: I'm trying to find some documentation somewhere but I have no clue how to use those methods.

Comment: Thanks @Théodvn - also a note, the `onKeyPress` on Android is triggering after the `onChange`. The docs say it should trigger before `onChange`. This might be an Android bug. I'll try to file it when I get time. All bugs I filed always get closed so I need to muster up the motivation and time haha.

Comment: @Dan I tested `e.nativeEvent.*` in actual RN build (non-Expo non-Snack) and it says "function not defined".

Answer (score 0):

You just want the text not to update in certain situations? You can always bind it to a state value and determine whether the state value should update:

```
class UncontrolledInput extends Component {
    state = {
      text: '',
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput value={this.state.text} onChangeText={this.handleChange} />
            </View>
        )
    }

    handleChange = text => {
        // only update if no 'i'
        if (!text.includes('i')) {
            this.setState({ text });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt but in my situation, there is a need to be uncontrolled. It's a complicated thing to explain, but as a simplified problem, i posed the question as "uncontrolled component".

Comment: Ah ok I see, interesting.